# Transfer data of Custom field from Quote to Order, when Quote is won

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am working on MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 with Sql server 2005.

I have created some new fields(attributes) on the Quote and QuoteProduct pages. I have created the same fields(attributes) on Order and OrderProduct pages. Now, the question is, if I won the quote, I want the data of new fields of Quote and QuoteProduct in the newly created fields of Order and OrderProduct.

Looking forward to hear from you. Many thanks.

Comment: I think the Entity Mapping functionality will be the remedy in this case. But, still I'm looking your answers.

Comment: I think the Entity Mapping or sometimes Hidden mapping functionality will be the remedy in this case. You can read about it at the following link:-

http://crmscape.blogspot.com/2009/06/ms-crm-40-entity-mapping-and-hidden.html

http://www.iotap.com/Blogs/tabid/277/EntryId/113/Relationship-Mapping-CRM-4-0.aspx

But, still I'm looking your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at Mappings under Quote_Order and QuoteDetail_OrderDetail relationships. There is a list of fields that will be mapped automatically when creating an Sales Order from Quote.